# When connecting hot to ground, lights turn on. Open neutral?

Tags: electrical, neutral

In troubleshooting one circuit, I accidentally discovered information for a second circuit that I've also been trying to sort out. So, bottom line is I was stupid and lucky. While replacing a switch on the first circuit (breaker off), I accidentally touched the hot to ground on a switch next to it which is on the second circuit (breaker on) with a ground wire and the lights on this second circuit came on.

This second circuit is a combination of lights and outlets with branch circuits. Part of this circuit works and part doesn't. As I said above, when I jumpered hot to ground, everything worked. I think this means there is an open neutral somewhere because the circuit was completed when connecting hot to ground. Is this correct? If so, how do I find the open neutral?

thank you.

Comment: Are these 2 circuits' breakers right next to each other? Do they share a single cable at any point?  Is the light which turned on rated for both 120V and 240V?  Could we see a photo of the inside of the box with the switches pulled back?

Comment: Yeah, that's messed up. If you have two entirely separate circuits then what happens on one should not affect the other. Something is definitely wrong here.

Comment: @Harper, It's the switches, not the breakers, that are next to one another. They don't share any wiring. I tone traced both circuits and know where each goes. The wiring configuration is the same for both: 14/2 in and 14/2 out with the black wires connected to the switch and the white wires wire nutted together.

Comment: Can you post photos of what's going on?

Comment: The blue and brown wires raise more questions.  What can you tell us about those?  Interestingly those are Euro colors but nothing in that box is made for Europe.  i was caught  off guard by the green wire nut on the neutrals but wire nut color doesn't matter (well not to wire function).

Comment: The switch in question is the one on the left. Ignore the blue and black wires; those go to an inverter for LED lighting on an entirely different circuit. The three switches in the image are on separate circuits.

Comment: @tws the breaker question was thinking about a multi wire branch circuit where 2 breakers share a neutral , although it looks right from what I can see on my phone I am wondering if the switched leg is on the neutral? This would not be to code but it would function.

Comment: @EdBeal, they do not share neutrals. The wire coming in on the left is the line and the ones on the right are load. The switch leg isn't on the neutral but the hot wires.

Comment: @Ed Beal, you were correct about them sharing a neutral previously. I inadvertently discovered it when I was fixing some open splices left by the previous administration. Once I separated them onto their own circuits, I was left with a partially working circuit. After tracing the wires, taking pictures on the J boxes, I drew out the circuit and figured out what needed to be connected where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved this myself by tracing the wires.  I figured out that two circuits had shared a neutral when I found two open splices, traced them back and separated onto separate circuits.  I didn't realize it at the time. Once I traced the wires, drew out the diagram and figured out there was no neutral, I figured out where to connect the neutral back in to complete the circuit. All working now.

[image: revised repaired circuit]
For posterity's sake, the original circuit diagram:

[image: original wiring diagram]

Comment: Since I pointed you in the correct direction after you saying they were not shared an up vote would be appropriate.